# Make PHP Output Errors As HTML Comment

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a production website for which I do not have access to the full file system; specifically, I can't view the error log.  The site is running under IIS.  However, I can edit the php ini.  There is a page that is not loading. I do not want to enable errors across the entire site, as I don't want to risk any sensitive information being revealed.

Is there a way to make PHP output all errors wrapped in a `<!-- -->` (a comment) and not make it visible to most users unless they check the source?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make PHP output all errors wrapped in a <!-- -->

Yes there is a built-in function. What you are looking for is [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). Juste copy/paste **Example #1** from PHP doc and replace  markup by your HTML comment markup.